# will not update npm with visual studio code

Tags: node.js, npm

Each time I try to update my npm, it comes up with a mistake.

This error also occurs if I also try to `install bootsrap` on npm.

I have version 3.3.12 of npm as I get notified via command prompt.

if i try to update npm I write:

```
npm install -g npm
```

and i have try to make this here:
[npm-windows-upgrade not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010088/npm-windows-upgrade-not-working)  and [How can I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows)

[Error with update on npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEzgT.png)

Comment: What is your node.js version?

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow this a : v10.4.0

Comment: try ``npm i -g npm@latest``

Comment: Same error @CaptainJackSparrow - just as it is in the picture.

Comment: try `npm install`